# Javascript - using arguments for closure, bad or good?

Tags: javascript, closures, private

Let's consider simple singleton implementation:

```
var singleton = function (Constructor) {
    var singleton;
    return function () {
        if (!singleton) {
            singleton = new Constructor();
        }
        return singleton;
    };
};
```

We could move declaration of *singleton* variable to arguments:

```
var singleton = function (Constructor, singleton) {
    return function () {
        if (!singleton) {
            singleton = new Constructor();
        }
        return singleton;
    };
};
```

So I simply curious about side effects.

One more example:

```
var counter = (function (i) {
    return function () {
        i = (i || 0) + 1;
        return i;
    };
}());
```

Comment: The `counter` example seems needlessly complicated, what with the `(i||0)` on every call. It would be easier to read _and_ more efficient to have `var i = 0;` in the outer function then the inner one could be a one-liner: `return ++i;`.

Answer (score 4):

> We could move declaration of singleton variable to arguments

First, let's make it possible to talk about this without tying outselves up in knots by using the same symbol (`singleton`) for two *completely* different things within the same few lines of code.

Here's your seecond example renamed:

```
var singleton = function (Constructor, instance) {
    return function () {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Constructor();
        }
        return instance;
    };
};
```

If you did that, then calling the `singleton` function with two arguments would specify `instance`, making passing `Constructor` in pointless — `Constructor` would never be called by `singleton` (again, if you passed in two args [and the second arg was truthy]). So it would be a bit odd to do that.

But you asked about side-effects. There are no *external* effects involved if you assign to a formal argument within the function. It doesn't, for instance, have any effect *outside* the function:

```
function foo(arg) {
    arg = 67;
}
var a = 42;
foo(a);
console.log(a); // Still 42
```

However, assigning to an argument rather than to a local variable does, in non-strict mode, have a small cost, because there's overhead involved: It relates to the magic `arguments` pseudo-array. In non-strict mode, there's a link between the formal arguments of a function and the `arguments` pseudo-array:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    b = 42;
    console.log(arguments[1]);
}
```

If we call that like this:

```
foo(1, 2);
```

we see

```
1
2
42
```

Note the magic: Assigning to the formal argument `b` updated the pseudo-array `arguments`. (It works the other way, too.) That link has a small but real runtime cost.

(In strict mode, there is no link, for this very reason.)

Comment: Wanted to add, that it's intricating and one can override the constructor and break the whole singleton.

Answer (score 1):

As far as `closure` goes, there is no difference in the two implementations. However, in first example, singleton is not settable by the caller.

I will choose between the two implementation, just based on whether singleton could have been created outside these example functions or not. If it can be, use `model 2` otherwise use `model 1`